# Make word list comma separated in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

I have long column of words

```
Rolls Royce
Volkswagen
Aston Martin
Audi
BMW
Mercedes-Benz
Porsche
Bentley
```

How to make these words comma separated like ...BMW,Audi...

Comment: Do you mean as  a VBA macro or in some other sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use find and replace with the following inputs:

```
find: ^p
replace: ,
```

Comment: Noted. You are most likely correct.